# AutoHotkey's Loop (read file contents) issues related to "+" symbol

Tags: loops, file-io, autohotkey

Referring to [**Loop (read file contents)**](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/LoopReadFile.htm), a quite strange thing happens every time I use a code like this one to run a script:

```
^+k::
{
    Gosub, MySub
}
Return

MySub:
{
    Send, +{Enter}
    Loop, read, C:\MyFile.txt
    {   
        temp = %A_LoopReadLine%
        Send, %temp%
        Send, +{Enter}
    }
}
Return
```

`MyFile.txt` is a simple text file where sometimes the "plus" symbol (`+`) is used together with normal letters and numbers.

Despite of this, however, what I see if I run the hotkey on an empty text file, either a Notepad or Microsoft Word blank sheet, is that every `+` is replaced by an underscore (`_`), an exclamation mark (`!`) or a question mark (`?`). I've seen an occurrence with a dollar symbol (`$`) replacement, too.

I tried to debug it printing on screen a message box with

```
MsgBox, %temp%
```

before sending text and it shows the original content of `MyFile.txt` perfectly.
Thus the issue should be on `Send` rather than on file reading.

The content of my file is something like this (repeated for about 20 rows more):

```
+---------------------------------
120001267381  ~ TEXT 0 10/20/18 VARIABLE  word text -> numbers: 17,000 x 108.99 | 109.26 x 15,000 ///  number = +5.500% some text
+---------------------------------
120001267381  ~ TEXT 0 10/20/18 VARIABLE  word text -> numbers: 17,000 x 108.99 | 109.26 x 15,000 ///  number = +5.500% some text
+---------------------------------
120001267381  ~ TEXT 0 10/20/18 VARIABLE  word text -> numbers: 17,000 x 108.99 | 109.26 x 15,000 ///  number = +5.500% some text
+---------------------------------
120001267381  ~ TEXT 0 10/20/18 VARIABLE  word text -> numbers: 17,000 x 108.99 | 109.26 x 15,000 ///  number = +5.500% some text
+---------------------------------
```

What can be the cause of this?

Comment: Please post the contents of your file.

Comment: Posted (see edit above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer: due to the fact that `+` symbols read from my file are sent like pressing the `Shift` key, the output is amended by the pressing of such a key instead of sending the original symbol present in file.

In order to send the original content of my file without triggering special hotkeys, I have to use `SendRaw` instead of `Send`, like in this example:

```
^+k::
{
    Gosub, MySub
}
Return

MySub:
{
    Send, +{Enter}
    Loop, read, C:\MyFile.txt
    {   
        temp = %A_LoopReadLine%
        SendRaw, %temp%
        Send, +{Enter}
    }
}
Return
```

Comment: Nice to see that you found the sendraw command yourself AND that you reported back.

Comment: Agreed. Accepting the answer would be even nicer :)

Comment: Wow, I'm glad you didn't read a line of text that had  `#rformat c:`  :)

Comment: @NelsonChan, are you really telling me that AutoHotkey would have erased my hard disk with such a line?! Wow...

Comment: Well, that's not the complete command to wipe your computer, but since the Send command replicates keystrokes, it could do really bad stuff if you aren't careful about what the parameters are.  

You don't need to use "Send" that way.  You can use the Clipboard and paste chunks of it instead.  I'll post an answer as a recommended alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an updated version that pastes using CTRL-V instead of Send to "retype" rows of data:

```
^+k::
{
    Gosub, MySub
}
Return

MySub:
{
    Send, +{Enter}
    Loop, read, C:\MyFile.txt
    {   
        temp = %A_LoopReadLine%
        Clipboard = %temp%   ; Write to clipboard
        Send, ^v+{enter}     ; Paste from clipboard
        Sleep 10             
; Short delay so it doesn't try to paste again before the clipboard has changed
; This check can get a lot more complex, but just increase it if 10 doesn't work
    }
}
Return
```